# create pandas dataframe from python dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create pandas dataframe from dictionary which should look like. the keys are the index and values are assign as first column.

```
Expected Output
2016-06-01 02:00:00      grey
2016-06-02 02:00:00     green
2016-06-03 02:00:00     green
.
.
.
.
2016-07-26 02:00:00     green
2016-07-27 02:00:00     green
2016-07-28 02:00:00     green
2016-07-29 02:00:00     green
2016-07-30 02:00:00     green
2016-07-31 02:00:00     green
```

but my code produce like this

```
df:       Date             DateValue
0 2016-06-01 02:00:00      grey
df:       Date             DateValue
0 2016-06-02 02:00:00     green 
df:      Date             DateValue
0 2016-06-03 02:00:00     green
df:     Date              DateValue
0 2016-07-25 02:00:00     green
df:     Date              DateValue
0 2016-07-26 02:00:00     green
df:     Date              DateValue
0 2016-07-27 02:00:00     green
df:     Date              DateValue
0 2016-07-28 02:00:00     green
df:     Date              DateValue
0 2016-07-29 02:00:00     green 
df:     Date              DateValue
0 2016-07-30 02:00:00     green
df:    Date               DateValue
0 2016-07-31 02:00:00     green
```

my database table data looks like this. it consists of two columns only. date and temperature values

```
usec        temp_data
1464739200  32
1464825600  31.32
1464912000  33.2
1464998400  29.56
.
.
.
.1469923200  28.45
```

dictionary looks like this after converting epoch time to datetime

```
data is here:  {datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 2, 0): 'grey'}
data is here:  {datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 2, 2, 0): 'green'}
.
.
.
data is here:  {datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 29, 2, 0): 'green'}
data is here:  {datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 30, 2, 0): 'green'}
data is here:  {datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 31, 2, 0): 'green'}
```

my code is as follow

```
import datetime
import calendar
import mysql.connector
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mysql.connector import errorcode


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='robbin', password='xxxx', database='rob')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

start_time = 1464739200

query = ("SELECT usec ,`temp_data` "
 "FROM rob_tab WHERE usec >= %s "
 "AND usec <= %s")

for i in range(61):
    current_start_ts = (start_time + (i*86400))
    current_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(current_start_ts)
    current_end_ts = (start_time + (i*86400)) + 86399
    cursor.execute(query, (current_start_ts , current_end_ts))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    rows_arr = np.array(rows)
    print 'type of the rows_arr: ', type(rows_arr)
    data = {}
    if len(rows_arr) == 0:
        data[current_day] = 'grey'
    else:
        for item, index in rows_arr:
            if index >= 34 or index <= 20:
                data[current_day] = 'red'
                break
            else:
                pass
                data[current_day] = 'green'
    df = pd.DataFrame(data.items(), columns=['Date', 'DateValue'])
    print df
```

when I use "print rows" the query results from database looks like

```
[(1469923200000000, 24.12361), (1469923800000000, 24.07994),
 (1469924400000000, 24.0237),..............(1469949000000000, 23.37064), 
 (1469949600000000, 23.48984), (1469950200000000, 23.61996), (1469950800000000, 23.82002)]
```

I am not able to produce correct dataframe. I tried to figure out the problem.
If somebody help me to solve this problem. I would be grateful.

Comment: maybe you should have print(df) out of the for loop ? can you try it?

Comment: @User193452 No, it gives IndentationError: unexpected indent.

Comment: what is the range 61?

Comment: @User193452 I am creating 2 months dates range, so i use range

Comment: what if you change abit this piece of code `df = pd.DataFrame(data.items(), columns=['Date', 'DateValue'])`into `df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'DateValue'])`? Alternatively you can use `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict` see the documentation here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: @arnold when using df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'DateValue'])   i got this error..................****raise ValueError('If using all scalar values, you must pass'
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
****               and for alternative i got this error.   ....AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'from_dict'

Comment: If I were you, I would read directly from the database, and then starts manipulating it when it is already in `pandas dataframe object`. Becasuse using `for` loop is expensive. Creating `DataFrame` from database could be achieved using `pandas.read_sql`. Here is the documentation of `read_sql`, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: @arnold thanks a lot for the tip. I would give it a try and will read the link you had given. I used for loop to extract certain range from database. How can I avoid this for loop. because your propose idea seems better. but I don't know how to use it accurately.

Comment: @arnold below one person give an answer. I had just one small question. his code line return me me empty. can you give it a look. because it fetch the data from database but inside for loop, it is not working. i tried my best. . the line is     reader=reader.loc[lambda df: (df.usec>=current_start_ts) & (df.usec<=current_end_ts),:]..........................i would be grateful.

Comment: @robbin, could you please provide some logic related to what you want to do with the original database? I have no clue of what you are trying to do with `usec` and `temp_data` to get the `date` and `datevalue` of either `red`, `green`, or `grey`.

Comment: @robbin, please see my answer below. Hope I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @arnold thanks a lot for the response. I will give it a look. Actually I was trying to get an pandas dataframe for usec and temperature column and plot calendar heatmap by using pandas. but i was unable to get an array of numbers. .i will come back in a moment after trying your solution which i am sure will work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, I understand the logic in your script correctly.

Here is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sql
from datetime import datetime

def add_column_date_value(row):
    usec = row['usec']
    current_start = row['current_start']
    current_end = row['current_end']
    temp_data = row['temp_data']
    if (usec >= current_start) and (usec <= current_end):
        if temp_data >= 34 or temp_data <= 20: return 'red'
        else: return 'green'
    else: return 'grey'

# hardcoded variables
start_time = 1464739200
number_of_samples = 4

conn = sql.connect('sample_db.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
tables = cur.fetchall()

for table_name in tables:
    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from %s" % table_name, conn)

for i in range(number_of_samples): # because I only have 4 sample data
    df.loc[i, 'current_start'] = start_time + (i*86400)
    df.loc[i, 'current_end'] = (start_time + (i*86400)) + 86399
    df.loc[i, 'date'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(df.loc[i, 'current_start'])

df['date_value'] = df.apply(add_column_date_value, axis=1)
df = df[['date','date_value']]
```

The results would be like the following:

```
    date                date_value
0   2016-06-01 07:00:00 green
1   2016-06-02 07:00:00 green
2   2016-06-03 07:00:00 green
3   2016-06-04 07:00:00 green
```

**Explanation**

I created the sample database that only takes the first 4 rows of the data you provided.

```
usec        temp_data
1464739200  32
1464825600  31.32
1464912000  33.2
1464998400  29.56
```

This codes dump all the tables in the database and then create a `pandas` `dataframe` for the table, since you only have 1 table in your database then I just simply assign it to a variable called `df`.

```
conn = sql.connect('sample_db.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
tables = cur.fetchall()

for table_name in tables:
    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from %s" % table_name, conn)
```

However, if you have multiple tables in your database, then I would advise you to assign them in the `dictionary`. Then change the `for loop` of the code above into something like the following.

```
d = dict()
for table_name in tables:
    d[table_name] = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from %s" % table_name, conn)
```

I just simplify your code of getting the `current_start_ts`, `current_end`, and `date` into something like this.

```
for i in range(number_of_samples): # because I only have 4 sample data
    df.loc[i, 'current_start'] = start_time + (i*86400)
    df.loc[i, 'current_end'] = (start_time + (i*86400)) + 86399
    df.loc[i, 'date'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(df.loc[i, 'current_start'])
```

At this moment, you should have the `dataframe` that is looked like this.

```
    usec        temp_data   current_start   current_end     date
0   1464739200  32.00       1.464739e+09    1.464826e+09    2016-06-01 07:00:00
1   1464825600  31.32       1.464826e+09    1.464912e+09    2016-06-02 07:00:00
2   1464912000  33.20       1.464912e+09    1.464998e+09    2016-06-03 07:00:00
3   1464998400  29.56       1.464998e+09    1.465085e+09    2016-06-04 07:00:00
```

In order to get the `date_value` you need to create a `function` first and then use `apply` method.

```
def add_column_date_value(row):
    usec = row['usec']
    current_start = row['current_start']
    current_end = row['current_end']
    temp_data = row['temp_data']
    if (usec >= current_start) and (usec <= current_end):
        if temp_data >= 34 or temp_data <= 20: return 'red'
        else: return 'green'
    else: return 'grey'

df['date_value'] = df.apply(add_column_date_value, axis=1)
```

Now you `df` should be like this, pardon for the formatting.

```
    usec    temp_data   current_start   current_end     date    date_value
0   1464739200  32.00   1.464739e+09    1.464826e+09    2016-06-01 07:00:00 green
1   1464825600  31.32   1.464826e+09    1.464912e+09    2016-06-02 07:00:00 green
2   1464912000  33.20   1.464912e+09    1.464998e+09    2016-06-03 07:00:00 green
3   1464998400  29.56   1.464998e+09    1.465085e+09    2016-06-04 07:00:00 green
```

If you want to keep only the `date` and `date_value`,

```
df = df[['date','date_value']]
```

The result of this `df` would be like this,

```
    date                date_value
0   2016-06-01 07:00:00 green
1   2016-06-02 07:00:00 green
2   2016-06-03 07:00:00 green
3   2016-06-04 07:00:00 green
```

Comment: I accept your answer because it give me idea how to get the dataframe. Actually Instead of grey, green and red. I need to generate an array of numbers. and then i can create the calendar heatmap . My main logic behing pandas dataframe is to create calendar heatmap easily. .Thanks a lot for your time and help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got the expected output:

```
query = '''SELECT * FROM rob_tab'''
reader=pd.read_sql(query,connection)
df=[]
for i in range(61):
    current_start_ts = (start_time + (i*86400))
    current_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(current_start_ts)
    current_end_ts = (start_time + (i*86400)) + 86399
    reader=reader.loc[lambda df: (df.usec>=current_start_ts) & (df.usec<=current_end_ts),:]
    rows_arr = np.array(reader)
    data = {}
    if len(rows_arr) == 0:
        data[current_day] = 'grey'
    else:
        for item, index in rows_arr:
            if index >= 34 or index <= 20:
                data[current_day] = 'red'
                break
            else:
                pass
                data[current_day] = 'green'

    for row in data.items():
            df.append({'Date': row[0], 'DateValue': row[1]})
    df2=pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df2)
```

is this what you expect?

```
        Date               DateValue
0  2016-06-01 02:00:00     green
1  2016-06-02 02:00:00      grey
2  2016-06-03 02:00:00      grey
3  2016-06-04 02:00:00      grey
4  2016-06-05 02:00:00      grey
5  2016-06-06 02:00:00      grey
6  2016-06-07 02:00:00      grey
7  2016-06-08 02:00:00      grey
```

small part of `raws_arr` in my case is:

```
[[  1.46473920e+09   3.20000000e+01]]
[]
[]
[]
[]]
```

And the result is :

```
      Date DateValue
0 2016-06-01 02:00:00     green
1 2016-06-02 02:00:00      grey
2 2016-06-03 02:00:00      grey
3 2016-06-04 02:00:00      grey
4 2016-06-05 02:00:00      grey
```

Then indeed when we have data,it is green and when we dont have it is grey.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am trying to use dictionary keys as index and the values as 1st column. your solution is creating dictionary but it create the keys as separate column and values are separate. so the problem will still remians the same. .

Comment: please check if the output is what you expect? then I update the answer

Comment: @User193452yes, but the dateValue are opposite. mean it follow this if index >= 34 or index <= 20: instruction and the results are like .  .grey, green, green, green,........

Comment: can you test the code of this answer with your data  @robbin

Comment: it gives me opposite values. I mean in the start of my question the output is show. I will add title with expected output. actually grey mean no data is there. .

Comment: I add title with expected output. .because I am trying to address data with...................grey = no data..................red = exceeded the limit..........green= within range. . your solutions is what i required but it give opposite output.

Comment: the rows_arr is empty. thats why it give opposite results. .so problem is in line ****** reader=reader.loc[lambda df: (df.usec>=current_start_ts) & (df.usec<=current_end_ts),:]

Comment: for me rows_arr is not empty, I updated the answer with the result of print(rows_arr)

Comment: indeed the data is there. i give output in the beginning of my question. the reader is empty. when i use print reader ..the output is ...........................Columns: [usec, temp_data]
Index: []....................

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144840/discussion-between-user193452-and-robbin).

Comment: what is the output of your reader line because in my code it is empty and that where the main problem is. ? thanks